Convert to std::optional in nlohmann::json via NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE
I need to serialize / deserialize a struct that has an optional member.
I'm using the excellent nlohmann::json library and from the docs I can see that it should be done like this:
namespace nlohmann {
template <typename T> struct adl_serializer<std::optional<T>> {
    static void to_json(json& j, const std::optional<T>& opt)
    {
        if (not opt.has_value()) {
            j = nullptr;
        }
        else {
            j = *opt; // this will call adl_serializer<T>::to_json which will
                      // find the free function to_json in T's namespace!
        }
    }

    static void from_json(const json& j, std::optional<T>& opt)
    {
        if (j.is_null()) {
            opt = std::nullopt;
        }
        else {
            opt = j.template get<T>(); // same as above, but with
                                       // adl_serializer<T>::from_json
        }
    }
};
} // namespace nlohmann

Now, ordinary conversions like these works:
std::optional<int32_t> opt_int{25};
j["k"] = opt_int.template get<std::optional<int32_t>>();

and vice versa
// note: no value in j
nlohmann::json j;
// this now calls from_json
std::optional<int> o = j["k"].template get<std::optional<int>>();

However, creating a struct and using
NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE:
struct TestStruct {
    int32_t                i;
    std::optional<int32_t> j;
};
NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(TestStruct, i, j);

Will now access the json keys with the at() call, yielding an exception:
nlohmann::json j = {
    {"i",      15}
};
// exception
auto ts = j.template get<TestStruct>();

Is it not possible to handle this when using NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE, so that if the key is absent, we just assign std::nullopt?

I don't know the answer to your question. But on a side note, you don't need to use template the way you are, eg j.template get<T>() should be j.get<T>(), opt_int.template<std::optional<int32_t>> should be just opt_int, j.template get<TestStruct>() should be j.get<TestStruct>(), etc...

Share the exception msg.

Try NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE_WITH_DEFAULT

@RemyLebeau, not true. Template is needed to disambiguate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838415/template-issue-with-nlohmannjson.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, It's not that interesting to see the message. It's simply "[json.exception.out_of_range.403] key 'EventData' not found". This is expected, since it is using the .at operator before calling the from_json.

@SupAl FWIW GCC 13.1 does it correctly, without the template.

@Botje, Yes, 11 does too. But MSVC does not and my code needs to be cross-platform.
